# Launch Convert Lead Window programmatically in LEX?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lead-conversion

We're wanting to interject some custom functionality into the standard Lead conversion process but still want to rely upon the native Lead Conversion feature to handle the conversion itself.

Is it possible to programmatically launch the "Convert Lead" modal in LEX? All research on my side has pointed to that not currently being possible?